# Error creating service connection to azure resource manager : azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure Resource Manager using managed identity - when trying to add service connection - so I can use another azure cloud app service to deploy to via pipelines.

I am getting this error when trying:

```
Service connection field 'creationMode' is not expected in Azure Resource Manager connections using the Managed Service Identity authentication scheme. Parameter name: endpoint.Data[creationMode]
```

I cant seem to figure out what I can do to not get this error.

Anyone received this before. Is it a permission thing?

Any ideas welcomed.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error in Azure DevOps creating a service Connection to azure.

The reason was, that I first selected "Service principal" and then went back and selected "Managed identity".

When I started from scratch it worked.

Just in case anyone arrives here with that error message.

Comment: This saved me a huge headache! The Service Connection blade page seems to cache information when selecting between the options. Res is correct - just navigate away and come back to the Create New Service Connection page and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

`creationMode` is one field used to represent the mode of endpoint creation. It's value is **Automatic** or **Manual**.

Not sure why you were getting message which relevant the field `creationMode` while it is configuring via `managed identity`. Because it is the one that `Service Principal Authentication` type used. It is not a expected field for `managed identity` type.

---

Troubleshooting way you can use:

**Step1**:

Use below [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get this issue service connection:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{service endpoint id}?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

**Step2**:

Then check whether `creationmode` exists in the response body of above api.

**Step3**:

- If exists, copy the response body, copy and paste it as request body. Here you
  are using `managed identity` to configure your Azure resource manager
  connection, so remove `creationMode` field data from the body. And
  run [Put api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to update this service connection.
- Even if it does not exists in that response body, you can also use
  this [Put api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to update your service connection with correct
  data. This can ensure the service connection creation data are
  correct.