# Unable to create Azure ARM Service Connection from Azure Devops using managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity

I try to create a ARM service connection from Azure Devops Project Settings.

I select Managed Identity as the connection type.
[image]

I fill the values for tenant id, subscription id , and subscription name with the other required values.
[image]
When I click on **Save** button , i get the below error:

```
Service connection field 'creationMode' is not expected in Azure Resource Manager connections using the Managed Service Identity authentication scheme. Parameter name: endpoint.Data[creationMode]
```

Can anyone help here? Thanks

Comment: Refer this SO thread answer for the same error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847089/error-creating-service-connection-to-azure-resource-manager-azure-pipelines#

Answer (score 0):

As per this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847089/error-creating-service-connection-to-azure-resource-manager-azure-pipelines#:%7E:text=Here%20you%20are%20using%20managed%20identity%20to%20configure,to%20update%20your%20service%20connection%20with%20correct%20data.) by **Res Riedel**  its a transient issue on Azure DevOps Portal. Start to create the service connection with Azure Resource Manager and Managed Identity from scratch like below and it will be succesfully created.

***Step 1:- Select New Service Connection > Azure Resource Manager > Next > Select Managed Identity>***

[image]

[image]

***Step 2:- Fill the Subscription ID and Tenant ID details of your Azure Subscription and Azure AD Tenant ID like below>***

[image]

***Step 3:- Give a unique name to your managed identity service connection> Click Save>***

[image]

***Service connection with managed identity got created successfully like below:-***

[image]